# Keyboard does not work after waking from suspend

Tags: keyboard

My keyboard a TTESPORTS Challenger KB - CHM does not work after suspend.  The backlights come on, but the operating system does not register input.

16.04.1

This is the output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 89e5:101b  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04d9:a09c Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```